# How to redirect internal directory strcuture in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Need some help with creating a redirection rule for internal directories to root.

**Exmaple1 :**

> `www.domain.com/page_1.asp   TO >>    www.domain.com/page/`

**Example2 :**

> `www.domain.com/page_110613.asp   To >>  www.domain.com/page/page_110613/`

**Example3 :**

> `www.domain.com/mailings/newsletter/anything/anyting/page.html
>   TO
>   www.domain.com/mailings/page

I am trying different ways using wordpress plugin (converting .asp site to Wordpress)

Comment: What is different between example1 and example2. Both seem to be same:  `page_<numbers>.asp`

Comment: example 1 ... redirecting page .asp to custom Archive
example2  ... redirecting .asp page to Single custom Post

Comment: Is it always `/page_1.asp` in example1 OR it can be ``/page_2.asp` also?